# Trying to use .reduce to return true if there are truthy values else false if there are falsey values

Tags: ruby, methods, reduce

Trying to use .reduce for course lesson... here is what they want my method to do:

```
  describe "reduce_to_all_true returns true when all values are truthy" do
    it "reduces correctly" do
      source_array = [1, 2, true, "razmatazz"]
      expect(reduce_to_all_true(source_array)).to be_truthy
    end
  end

  describe "reduce_to_all_true returns false when any value is false" do
    it "reduces correctly" do
      source_array = [1, 2, true, "razmatazz", false]
      expect(reduce_to_all_true(source_array)).to be_falsy
    end
  end
```

I am having a hard time understanding this...here is my code:

```
def reduce_to_all_true(source_array)
    source_array.reduce { |beTrue| if beTrue == true; p true; else p false end}
end
```

The error I get:

```
  1) my own reduce-like methods reduce_to_all_true returns true when all valuesare truthy reduces correctly
     Failure/Error: expect(reduce_to_all_true(source_array)).to be_truthy

       expected: truthy value
            got: false
```

Any help/explanation would be much appreciated!

Comment: It's a pity that `&&` is not a method in ruby. Else this would have worked: `source_array.reduce(&:'&&')`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev If you're dealing with real booleans (rather than truthy and falsey) then there's always `array_of_booleans.inject(:&)`.

Comment: @muistooshort: works on arrays too, beautifully :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `source_array.all? `

Comment: @steenslag: *slaps forehead* but of course! Doesn't use reduce, though :)

Comment: I ended up passing the complete lesson putting an if statement within the block. Thanks everyone.

Comment: @steenslag: that deserves to be an answer, because it answers the implicit question behind the question as asked, and is likely the correct solution for most folks who'd find this question.  Would you like to write it as one, or shall I (or someone else seeing this later, and not seeing it as an answer still)?  :)

Comment: @lindes  Well it solves the problem (it short-circuits which is nice) but does not answer the question - I did not know how to handle that. You go ahead if you do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand the difference between "truthiness"/"falsiness" and being `true`/`false`.

Ruby would evaluate everything that is not `nil` or `false` as truthy, so you can write:

```
puts 1 if 1
```

and it will puts 1.

In this assignment you're asked to use truthiness, so instead of comparing to `true` you can use ruby to do the conversion for you using double negation `!!`:

```
pry> [1, "2", nil, true, false].map{|e| !!e}
=> [true, true, false, true, false]
```

Also note that a block in `reduce` accepts two params - one is the current element and another one is accumulator -  the result of interating over previous elements. Use both in the block, otherwise you'll be returning result depending only on the last element of the array.

Comment: What, another reduce question? Did astronomers declare Week of the Reduce? :)

Comment: From the same user too.

Comment: "one is the current element and another one is accumulator " - it's the other way around, btw. You're thinking of `each_with_object` :)

Comment: I still don't understand but that just means I have to go back and learn some more. Still don't understand what reduce is doing to return true if it's truthy and false if falsey. Thanks though

Comment: @RoderickCardenas: I guess it does take some time to "click". `reduce` (or `fold`, as known in some other languages) collapses/reduces/folds a collection into a single value. You just have to provide logic of the incremental update of the accumulator. Important point: "incremental".

Comment: I did it. Your comment helped me think about the '&&' So : def reduce_to_all_true(source_array)
    source_array.reduce { |beTrue, beFalse| beTrue && beFalse}
end

Comment: @RoderickCardenas: yep, this code is functional, but the names are terrible. Aside from being in camelCase, `beTrue` and `beFalse` do NOT accurately describe what those parameters mean.

Comment: As mentioned in a comment under the question, `Array#all?` is a thing, and is probably ultimately the desired solution here.  Not submitting it as an answer in the moment in case @steenslag wants to, but placing it as a comment here in case folks look.  It could also just be an edit to this already-accepted answer, and do well.

Answer (score 0):

### Alternative answer:

For those not doing this for a course, where the point is specifically to explore using `reduce`, the `all?` method on arrays may be useful:

```
[true, 1, "2"].all?                # => true
[true, 1, "2", false].all?         # => false
```

### Further discussion of the above:

Of note to those comparing this with using `and` more directly: this does *not* do "short-circuiting" — that is, all elements in the array will get evaluated:

```
[false,puts("test"),false].all?
test                               # printed
# => false                         # returned
```

Compare:

```
false and puts("test") and false
# => false                         # returned
# [nothing gets printed]
```

Of course, this really all happens before `#all?` is even called... it's as if one had done this:

```
arr = [false,puts("test"),false]
test                               # printed
arr
# => [false, nil, false]           # value of arr
arr.all?
# => false                         # returned
```

Still, I thought it was worth noting, as some may expect a short-circuiting behavior.